# Getting std::complex<double> to pass std::is_floating_point test

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-assert

I want the types `double`, `float`, `complex<double>` and `complex<float>` to pass a `static_assert` condition. I figured `static_assert(std::is_floating<T>::value, "some message")` would do the trick, but the complex types do not pass this test (at least under gcc-4.10).

What predicate would I add to make sure these four types (and perhaps `long double`s as well) are allowed as template instantiations, but nothing else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is generally illegal to add specializations for standard library type trait classes, even for user-defined types. §20.10.2 [meta.type.synop]/p1:

> The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the
>   class templates defined in this subclause is undefined unless
>   otherwise specified.

Currently, the only type trait class that users are allowed to add specializations for is `std::common_type`, if at least one template parameter in the specialization is a user-defined type (§20.10.7.6 [meta.trans.other], Table 57).

You need to write your own trait, which isn't hard:

```
template<class T>
struct is_complex_or_floating_point : std::is_floating_point<T> { };

template<class T>
struct is_complex_or_floating_point<std::complex<T>> : std::is_floating_point<T> { };
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/y7U2p5).

Comment: Nice didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html), they provide `boost::is_complex` for use with `std::complex`.

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<float>::value, "some message");
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<double>::value, "some message");
    static_assert(boost::is_complex<std::complex<float>>::value, "some message");
    static_assert(boost::is_complex<std::complex<double>>::value, "some message");
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68562371db8c8cbb)</kbd>