# Object-oriented API for equations

Tags: c++, oop, equation

Let's take the Quadratic equation as an example:

```
a x^2 + b x + c = 0
```

This equation can be viewed as describing a relation between the values a, b, c, and x. Given three of those, you can calculate the fourth. The four possibilities are:

```
a = - (b x + c) / x^2
b = - (a x^2 + c) / x
c = - x (a x + b)
x = [-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4 a c)] / (2 a)
```

Here's one approach to representing this equation. Given the following class:

```
class Quadratic
{

public: 

    double a; bool HasA = false; void A(double a_) { a = a_; HasA = true; }
    double b; bool HasB = false; void B(double b_) { b = b_; HasB = true; }
    double c; bool HasC = false; void C(double c_) { c = c_; HasC = true; }
    double x; bool HasX = false; void X(double x_) { x = x_; HasX = true; }

    // a = - (b x + c) / x^2

    double A()
    {
        if (HasB == false) throw domain_error("B not set");
        if (HasC == false) throw domain_error("C not set");
        if (HasX == false) throw domain_error("X not set");

        if (x == 0.0) throw domain_error("X cannot be 0.0");

        return - (b*x + c) / (x*x);
    }

    // x = [-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4 a c)] / (2 a)

    vector<double> X()
    {
        if (HasA == false) throw domain_error("A not set");
        if (HasB == false) throw domain_error("B not set");
        if (HasC == false) throw domain_error("C not set");

        if (a == 0.0) throw domain_error("A cannot be 0.0");

        return 
        { 
            (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4 * a*c)) / (2 * a),
            (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4 * a*c)) / (2 * a)
        };
    }

    // b = - (a x^2 + c) / x
    // ...

    // c = - x (a x + b)
    // ...
};
```

We can find `x` as follows. Set `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
obj.A(2.3);
obj.B(3.4);
obj.C(1.2);
```

There might be two values for `X` so iterate through the result:

```
for each (auto elt in obj.X()) cout << elt << endl;
```

If any of the dependent values are not set, a `domain_error` exception is thrown.

Similarly, to find `A`, we set `B`, `C`, and `X`:

```
obj.B(1.2);
obj.C(2.3);
obj.X(3.4);
```

and display the result:

```
cout << obj.A() << endl;
```

My question is, are there other approaches to representing and working with equations in an object-oriented language? Is there a more idiomatic approach than the above?

Comment: Not sure this is quite enough for a full-blown answer but it seems to me that one will hardly ever want to find "a", or "b", or "c" given an instance of Quadratic.. that is quite simply a linear equation; if the notion of Quadratic is to make sense, "x" is what you want to be referring to.
You could improve this (IMHO) by making a Polynomial<T> class, that can store a polynomial for any coefficient type T, and which has operations like std::vector<T> FindZeros(); Calculate(T). Above a certain polynomial degree, there are no closed form solution formulas IIRC, so be ready to approximate!

Comment: @EnricoGranata The following is an equation for displacement as a function of time: `1/2 ax t^2 + v*t + xi - xf = 0` (given acceleration, initial velocity, time, initial displacement, and final displacement). In college physics problems, it's common to have to solve for one of these.

Comment: true - if you're solving for "t", then it's a quadratic equation, if you're solving for any other variable then it's a linear equation. It seems weird to me that your object model would allow you to misname things ("Quadratic" being solved as linear). Maybe you should let your coefficient class be Constant or Variable, and if variable have itself a coefficient and a degree, then you would be able to generally express polynomial functions of multiple variables

Comment: @EnricoGranata I'm just using this formula as an example. :-)

Comment: [Mathematics is a language in itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_of_mathematics). The concise way of representing math is using a less constrained and more functional language. C++ can do that, using templates, lambdas and a lot of other (especially recently added) features. If you really want to be serious about this, look at how professional math software does it, and go from there. [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is one of the best ones out there. You definitely want to take at least a look or two to cast better design decisions for your own stuff.

Comment: I would replace `HasA` with `a = 0`. I also do not see why `a` cannot be 0.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question says:

> Object-oriented API for equations

However, there is nothing object-oriented about your code example, at least not with the established definitions of "object-oriented programming" I know. **You have no virtual functions, so it's not object-oriented.**

Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ [*"What is "OOP" and what's so great about it?"*](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#oop) says (emphasis added by me):

> In the context of C++ [...] it means programming using class hierarchies and **virtual
>   functions** to allow manipulation of objects of a variety of types
>   through well-defined interfaces and to allow a program to be extended
>   incrementally through derivation.

The Standard C++ FAQ (which also quotes from the first source), answers [*"Are virtual functions (dynamic binding) central to OO/C++?"*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#virt-is-central-to-oo) like this:

> Without virtual functions, C++ wouldn’t be object-oriented.

---

Therefore,

> My question is, are there other approaches to representing and working
>   with equations in an object-oriented language?

The answer to that should be that **mathematical computations and object-orientation programming usually do not mix well**. Object orientation is all about choosing the concrete implementation of an abstract operation at run-time. You may, for example, choose a different algorithm with the same input and output based on the user's choice at **run-time**. This could be done with virtual functions. Still, the object-orientation would happen at a higher level of your application, and the computation itself would not be object-oriented.

> Is there a more idiomatic approach than the above?

Yes, **generic programming**, i.e. templates.

All the code you presented works with `double` values. What if I want to use it with `float`, `std::complex<double>` or a even a custom `BigNumber` class?

With templates, you can write generic code with concrete implementations chosen at **compile-time**.

First of all, let's make your original code compilable:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <math.h>

class Equation
{
public:
    bool HasA;
    bool HasB;
    bool HasC;
    bool HasX;

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double x;


    double A()
    {
        if (!HasB) throw std::domain_error("B not set");
        if (!HasC) throw std::domain_error("C not set");
        if (!HasX) throw std::domain_error("X not set");

        if (x == 0.0) throw std::domain_error("X cannot be 0.0");

        return - (b*x + c) / (x*x);
    }

    // x = [-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4 a c)] / (2 a)

    std::vector<double> X()
    {
        if (!HasA) throw std::domain_error("A not set");
        if (!HasB) throw std::domain_error("B not set");
        if (!HasC) throw std::domain_error("C not set");

        if (a == 0.0) throw std::domain_error("A cannot be 0.0");

        return 
        { 
            (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4 * a*c)) / (2 * a),
            (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4 * a*c)) / (2 * a)
        };
    }

    // b = - (a x^2 + c) / x
    // ...

    // c = - x (a x + b)
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    Equation e;
    std::vector<double> v = e.X();
}
```

*(I've fixed the `== false` comparisons, which are almost always bad style, but there is more work to do from a C++ coding quality POV, e.g. making the member variables private.)*

The problem is that this whole thing only works for `double`s. If you try to use it with `int`s, here's what happens:

```
int main()
{
    Equation e;
    std::vector<int> v = e.X();
}
```

Result:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

Here's how you can turn your class into a template: add `template <class T>` on top and replace every `double` with `T` (and add two `static_cast`s to tell the compiler that you agree with a narrowing conversion which may happen due to `sqrt`'s return type):

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <math.h>

template <class T>
class Equation
{
public:
    bool HasA;
    bool HasB;
    bool HasC;
    bool HasX;

    T a;
    T b;
    T c;
    T x;


    T A()
    {
        if (!HasB) throw std::domain_error("B not set");
        if (!HasC) throw std::domain_error("C not set");
        if (!HasX) throw std::domain_error("X not set");

        if (x == 0.0) throw std::domain_error("X cannot be 0.0");

        return - (b*x + c) / (x*x);
    }

    // x = [-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4 a c)] / (2 a)

    std::vector<T> X()
    {
        if (!HasA) throw std::domain_error("A not set");
        if (!HasB) throw std::domain_error("B not set");
        if (!HasC) throw std::domain_error("C not set");

        if (a == 0.0) throw std::domain_error("A cannot be 0.0");

        return 
        { 
            static_cast<T>((-b + sqrt(b*b - 4 * a*c)) / (2 * a)),
            static_cast<T>((-b - sqrt(b*b - 4 * a*c)) / (2 * a))
        };
    }

    // b = - (a x^2 + c) / x
    // ...

    // c = - x (a x + b)
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    Equation<int> e;
    std::vector<int> v = e.X();
}
```

Of course, this is only half of the story, because chances are very high that you do **not want to allow integral types** anyway, only floating-point types like `double` or `float` (or custom floating-point types). The result of `sqrt(2)` truncated to `1` is rarely desirable.

To keep your code generic but prevent such problems, read up on [**static assertions**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) for compile-time checks, restricting your template to particular types. [`std::is_floating_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) may be useful, too. See also the following recent question on SO:

[Getting std::complex<double> to pass std::is_floating_point test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345206/getting-stdcomplexdouble-to-pass-stdis-floating-point-test)

And remember, nothing of this has anything to do with object-oriented programming.